How to load source content when the source was changed in vscode debugger
I am implementing custom functionality while debugging a remote program.
Once I add new functionality I have to change the source content of the debugge.how to achieve this.
I tried loadedsource event reason change in dap but it’s not working.
Once I add new functionality I have to change the source content of the debugge.how to achieve this.
I tried loadedsource event reason change in dap but it’s not working
